# sudo -i for a 'nologin' account

Tags: sudo

I have an account

```
grafana:x:494:494:Grafana User:/tmp:/sbin/nologin
```

I want to use to run a container. If I do

```
jsmith$ sudo -u grafana -s TMPDIR=/bs XDG_DATA_HOME=/bs XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/bs podman run --network-config-dir=/bs -it alpine
```

I get: "cannot chdir to /home/jsmith: Permission denied". I can run the command OK if I first chdir to a dir that is writable by grafana. However, I want to start this from a startup script without changing directory, i.e. with a single command. I can't figure out how. Setting HOME doesn't help. I am only able to get around this by using

```
jsmith$ sudo su -l -s /bin/bash -c 'XDG_DATA_HOME=/bs XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/bs podman run --network-config-dir=/bs -it alpine' grafana
```

But that kind of seems circtuitous.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this could be achieved in two ways:

The first way would be to change the account so it is able to log in:

```
grafana:x:494:494:Grafana User:/tmp:/bin/bash
```

This could be a potential security risk, so if you do not want that, you could consider using a systemd Unit file to start this, instead of a startup script.

Save this to /etc/systemd/system/[mycontainer].service: (Replace mycontainer with a name that suits you.)

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Container
AssertPathExists=/bs

[Service]
User=grafana
Group=grafana
Environment="XDG_DATA_HOME=/bs"
Environment="XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/bs"
Environment="TMPDIR=/bs"
ExecStart=podman run --network-config-dir=/bs -it alpine
Nice=5
# Uncomment this if you want the container to be started on boot, otherwise don't
#[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run `systemctl enable mycontainer` and you can use `systemctl start mycontainer` and `systemctl stop mycontainer` to manage it.

For more information on Systemd units, I've found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When running rootless Podman, Podman by default stores its
containers and container images in the home directory.

The directory */tmp* is writable by any user, so it would be
better to let the user **grafana** have its own home directory.

```
$ sudo useradd grafana -s /sbin/nologin -c "Grafana User"
$ grep grafana /etc/passwd
grafana:x:1025:1025:Grafana User:/home/grafana:/sbin/nologin
$ sudo systemd-run --machine=test1@ \
                    --quiet \
                    --user \
                    --collect \
                    --pipe \
                    --wait \
                       podman \
                         run \
                         --rm \
                         docker.io/library/alpine echo hello
Trying to pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 8921db27df28 done
Copying config 042a816809 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
hello
$
```

I see the text *"hello"* in the output from the command `echo hello`.

The test worked fine.

#### Another test

If you want */tmp* to be the home directory but instead let Podman only use for example */var/bs*, you could probably make it work by passing in the same environment variables as in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731226/9360) by @Anuril.

I added the options

```
  -E XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/bs \
  -E XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/var/bs \
  -E TMPDIR=/var/bs \
```

to the above systemd-run command but the command failed with

`ERRO[0000] stat /tmp/.config/containers/storage.conf: permission denied`

I then tried also adding

```
  -E HOME=/var/bs \
```

but the command failed with the error message:

`Error relocating /bin/echo: RELRO protection failed: Permission denied`

For details see:

```
$ useradd test2 -s /sbin/nologin -c "Grafana User" -d /tmp
$ grep test2 /etc/passwd
test2:x:1026:1026:Grafana User:/tmp:/sbin/nologin
$ sudo mkdir /var/bs
$ sudo chown test2:test2 /var/bs
$ sudo systemd-run \
                    -E XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/bs \
                    -E XDG_CONFIG_DIR=/var/bs \
                    -E TMPDIR=/var/bs \
                    -E HOME=/var/bs \
                    --machine=test2@ \
                    --quiet \
                    --user \
                    --collect \
                    --pipe \
                    --wait \
                       podman \
                         run \
                         --rm \
                         docker.io/library/alpine echo hello
Trying to pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 8921db27df28 done  
Copying config 042a816809 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
Error relocating /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: RELRO protection failed: Permission denied
Error relocating /bin/echo: RELRO protection failed: Permission denied
$
```

I don't know why it's failing.